# Is there any method to edit a text file without opening it?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a text file which has about 70000000 lines in Linux system.

How to delete the lines from 40000000 to 50000000 without opening the file?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the concept opening a file is now used properly. In order to make any changes to a file, you'd have to call open(2) before doing anything else.

Comment: Sami is right : opening from a user's perspective or from a syscall perspective? If the former, see the below answer. If the latter, no.

Comment: Well there's always the [butterfly command for emacs...](http://xkcd.com/378/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the command "sed".

```
sed -i '<\line_no_start>,<\line_no_end>d' <\filename>
```

Example:  To delete lines 4 to 6 from file 'sample.txt'.

```
sed -i '4,6d' sample.txt
```